# How can I apply a background to a container around my content and not HTML?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to set the background of my page to fill a div container around my content and not use the HTML selector to set the background because a teacher has told me this isn't good syntax.

The issue is, I'm finding my container background isn't applying to the push div and footer. Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here in your CSS:

```
.footer, .push {
    height: 40px;
}
```

This is overriding your rules that have been already applied (your `.wrapper` and `.container` rules at the top). Try getting rid of this rule or commenting it out to test if it fixes your problem.

EDIT: You also don't seem to have a `.footer` element in your main page. This could be why that rule is not working. Try removing that `.` before the footer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First you better set the background to the body element.

and your footer have a background property of its own.